# PWM and DC motor speed

Tags: motor, dc, pwm

I'm hoping to try to control the rpm of a DC motor. AFAIK, I'd need to generate PWM for that. How does one find out which frequency is needed for a certain rpm? Is the frequency of the PWM signal supposed to be related to the speed of the motor?

Thanks

Comment: It's not the frequency. It's the duty cycle that is related to the speed of the motor. Use google first. you will find a [lot of information](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pulse-width-modulation).

Comment: see my answer here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/473410/how-to-calculate-speed-of-dc-motor/642994#642994

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of the PWM speed control of a motor is that you switch the motor on and off between between 0V and its max operating voltage at a fast rate. It is common to use a frequency that is higher than the range of hearing so that this fast switching is not creating an annoying noise in your head.

The actual speed of the motor becomes related to the length of time the fast switching time has the voltage attached to the motor versus the length of time the voltage to the motor is switched off. This time relationship is referred to as the duty cycle of the signal. Change the duty cycle and the speed changes.

Comment: Say, with a 3V motor that gives 4kg/cm torque when it runs at 25rpm. It maxes out at 250rpm. Is there a non-PWM way to make it run at 25rpm? Hooking it up directly to a power source will make it run at 250rpm - correct?

Comment: @JohnMunroe - You can connect the motor to a varying voltage level to control the speed. When the motor is connected to its rated voltage it should run at its full RPM. Lower voltages will lower the RPM and will also lower the available torque. A variable speed drive for the motor that uses voltage variation can be very inefficient because the voltage drop from supply to motor needs to be burned up as heat in some components. On the other hand with the fast switching of PWM there is never a high voltage drop across the switches so power loss is much lower. The windings of (continued)

Comment: (continued from above)  the motor take care of integrating the high frequency PWM pulses into a net effective voltage that the motor operates on. PWM has its advantages also in that the PWM can be set to a higher duty cycle just as the motor is turned on to over come the initial inertia get the motor moving and can then be cut back to the running duty cycle. PWM for a motor is often very conveniently provide via software in a microcontroller or via a programmed timer on the microcontroller that generates the timing waveform.

Comment: The spec of this motor I'm looking at says that it can give 4kg/cm torque when running at 25RPM. 0.56kg/cm when running at 250RPM. All at 3V. So is it really 3V in both cases or is the voltage when run at 250RPM supposed to be higher?

Comment: @JohnMunroe - The specs for the motor may be assuming that there is 3V applied to the motor and when you apply a load to the motor that is smaller then the motor is able to run fast. When the load is increased the motor slows down as it has to deliver more torque to the load. Be careful to not stall the motor in such situation with too much load as often this can lead to overheating and burning of the windings in the motor. Note also that in this scenario that as the load is increased to slow down the motor the torque increases but also the current from the supply also increases.

Comment: Right. So you mean it's not the PWM that slows the RPM to 25 in order to produce 4kg/cm but rather the load itself is creating a resistance for the motor such that 4kg/cm torque is produced? [This is the motor I'm referring to](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/JA12-N20-gear-motor-micro-gear-motor-intelligent-robots-smart-car-motor-3-6-12V-/151256827721?var=&hash=item23379c0749:m:mN8aGBancL6wMtH5dXE3wiQ).

Comment: @JohnMunroe - Yes that would be the case in the testing of a particular unit. But I see that you are mixing up your data. The separate rows of data in the chart given on the eBay page are showing characteristics for a different motor assembly in each row. The 3V at 250 rpm row is for a motor assembly with its gear box setup in a 30:1 ratio such that 250 rpm is generated at no load. On the other hand the row of 3V at 25 rpm is setup with a 298:1 gear ratio to produce a 25 rpm no load running speed.

Comment: Oh! Each row is a different gear box setup, essentially a different product sold! Now everything makes sense. :)

Comment: @JohnMunroe - I suspect that the motor on these gear boxes is the same motor for all products. Such motor is capable of running at any voltage from 3 to 12V. As you can see the 3V, the 6V and 12V rows repeat the same gear ratios of 10, 30, 50, 100, 150, 200, 298 and 380. I also suspect that the stall current for the 6V row at 380 gear ratio is a typo and should be 200mA.

Comment: I'd like to note that you're not going to get precise speed control using just PWM. Think about a 25 percent duty on a loaded and unloaded motor - clearly, the duty is the same but the speed will be different. For more precision work, you'll need a tachometer or encoder to estimate your speed. Once you have that, you should be able to design a simple PID that will get you where you want to be.

Comment: "The idea of the PWM speed control of a motor is that you switch the motor on and off between between 0V and its max operating voltage at a fast rate." Couldn't you use a cap and an op amp.

Comment: @WKleinberg - You may certainly be able to create a PWM frequency generator with an opamp, a capacitor and a few resistors but in the general case that will never have the capability to directly drive a motor.

Answer (score 2):

DC motors pretty much respond to varying voltage by varying their speed. PWM is a means of getting a varying voltage in a digital-friendly fashion from a fixed voltage supply.

The frequency should be chosen with respect to your filter, or your filter should be chosen with respect to your frequency.

The duty cycle (on time .vs. off-time) is proprtional to the output voltage (100% on - full voltage of supply - 0% on, 0 volts, 50% on, 50% voltage of supply...)

Comment: But doesn't a DC motor still run with a fixed voltage supply? rpm = voltage * kv of motor - correct?

Comment: Speed varies with voltage (actually with voltage and applied torque) PWM is a means of varying speed by varying voltage. if the torque load is fixed you can fix the voltage and arrive at the fixed voltage however you like. PWM does offer the potential to sense the speed and alter the voltage to respond to varying torque loading.