# How to calculate speed of DC Motor?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

I have a DC motor rated 24VDC@200mA driving at 40% DC and 20% DC(PWM) should run at what speed? Is there any formula to calculate the motor speed based on duty cycle

Answer (score 4):

No. You cannot calculate the speed based on the duty cycle.
The duty cycle dictates the average power supplied to the motor, and although this is proportional to motor speed for certain regions of operation, no direct relationship exists in all cases. The speed at a given power will depend on the load. This is why a tiny motor whips round at no load and slows down at the same power with a fan on the end. The best way to measure the speed of a dc motor is to use some form of encoders. Most encoders use infrared light in a beam that gets cut by a serrated wheel of plastic attached to the back of the motor. If you have a brushless motor it is likely that it has magnetic sensors. Those can be used to determine position over time (speed) too.

Comment: Suppose I have some load say it 3 then how to calculate the speed based on the duty cycle.

Comment: The duty cycle dictates the applied voltage, so, not directly the applied power as current can still vary.

Comment: @Harsha A load of 3 ...? 3 what? If you have a torque vs speed graph of the motor, you can determine eventually what voltage you need to apply. Or een better: if you know the torque constant and the speed constant of the motor.

Comment: My motor ratings are 24VDC@200mA with 5W power. At this point of time we are not considering any load and giving the duty cycle as the input to the dc motor and calculating the speed. want to confirm that the motor is rotating according to the given duty cycle or not. Is output from motor is as per the input given?

Comment: "*My motor ratings are 24VDC@200mA with 5W power.*" You already said that in the title and in the question. There is no need to keep repeating it. Please try to answer the questions asked in the comments. A load of 3 what? Watts? Nm? Turkeys? Do you have the datasheet link for the motor? Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: A load of 5W is there

Comment: You say the motor is rated for 24VDC@200mA, which is 4.8W. Is this the '5W' you are referring to? What is the specified motor rpm at 24V? (If you don't know, tell us the motor part number and/or a link to the motor on the supplier or manufacturer's website).

Comment: DC motor rs775 , 12v -24v large torque motor from thermisto.

Answer (score 1):

If the PWM is being applied to to the motor properly (current recirculated through the motor during PWM 'off' period, and frequency high enough to smooth current via the winding inductance) then the speed of a permanent magnet DC motor should be  proportional to the PWM ratio. PWM creates an average voltage equal to the supply voltage multiplied by the PWM ratio, so the motor should spin at the same speed that it would with the equivalent lower DC voltage.

So for example if the motor spins at 10,000 rpm on 24 V then with 40% PWM applied it should run at 10,000*0.4 = 4,000 rpm. With 20% PWM it should run at 10,000*0.2 = 2,000 rpm. This is equivalent to running the motor on 9.6 V or 4.8 V.

Comment: This has not been my experience. What I have seen is that some minimum duty factor is required just to overcome friction. I wouldn't expect your example motor to run at 100 rpm if the duty factor is 1%...I would expect that it doesn't turn at all.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson But you also wouldn't expect the motor to run if you applied a 0.24V supply to it. I guess the question is whether a motor behaves the same with a PWM applied to it of duty cycle D from a supply VDC, as it does if you just applied VDC x D straight from a supply.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson A motor may actually run at lower PWM ratio than on the equivalent DC voltage because the vibration helps to overcome 'stiction'. Some model railway controllers deliberately use low frequency PWM to get lower speed and avoid 'jack rabbit' starts.

Comment: I tested a small 12VDC brushed motor on a supply voltage of 11V, with various PWM ratios and the equivalent DC voltages. Between 20% and 80% PWM the speeds tracked within +-7% of each other (eg. 48% PWM = 9180rpm, 5.28VDC = 9090rpm). At 8% PWM the DC speed was 20% lower than the PWM speed. On 0.66VDC it would not start or run, but on 6% PWM it did 1020rpm. Based on the rpm at 11V (and assuming Kv remains constant) it should do 1100rpm on 0.66V, so the low speed PWM was _more_ linear than DC!

Comment: What was the RPM with a duty factor of 1%? My point really has nothing to do with running on dc, but rather that your assertion that speed should be proportional to PWM duty factor is only true when the duty factor is above some minimum value.

Comment: @DKNguyen My comment has nothing to do with applying dc voltages. My point is that we can't say "RPM is proportional to PWM duty factor" without mentioning that this only applies if the duty factor is above some minimum value.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Speed will be proportional to PWM duty factor when the duty factor is above some minimum value, so what is that minimum value?

Comment: @Harsha I think it depends on the motor, whether powered by PWM or DC. I tested a coreless motor which has very low brush drag and zero cogging. It is rated for 35,000 rpm at 24V. At 0.2V (the lowest voltage it would run on) it did 330 rpm, which is close to the theoretical speed of 292 rpm based on a Kv of 35000/24 = 1458rpm/V. 0.2V equates to less than 1% PWM at 24V.

Comment: @Harsha The minimum duty factor will depend on the mechanical and electrical characteristics of the motor. That was exactly my original point...you can't blindly assume that RPM is **always** proportional to DF.

Comment: Nothing in this world is perfect. Theoretically a DC motor's speed is precisely linearly proportional to voltage at all speeds. In practice this is only approximately so, but close enough for most purposes. This applies to all electronic components too, even capacitors and resistors  - all have nonlinearities, noise, drift, and anomalous behavior outside their normal operating range.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the less speed - the more difficult to increase the speed. So the differential equation should look like \$d'(v) = ad(v)\$. The solution is \$d(v) = e^{av}\$. It corresponds to my data:

[image]

But \$d(v)=e^{av^2}\$ is actually better, \$d(v)=e^{av^3}\$ is the best.