# Motor 12V 16RPM - how to calculate RPM based on PWM?

Tags: arduino, pwm, dc-motor, motor-controller

I bought a motor specified for 16 RPM at 12V. This motor is controlled using an L293D integrated circuit to control speed and direction.

This is the manufacturer's specification table for the different motors they sell. I have the 16RPM @ 12V

[image]

In my Arduino code I’m using PWM to control speed.

`analogWrite(motorpin, 255);`

The above code I will give me the maximum RPM - that's 16 RPM. Is the duty cycle is proportional so that `analogWrite(motorpin, 127);`  will give me 8RPM?

Is there anything else to consider to get the exact RPM based on the duty cycle?

Comment: `Is there anything else to consider to get the exact RPM based on the duty cicle?` - motors like this just are not that **exact** so lower your expectations please.

Comment: You can make such a calculation or look up table, but it will only be valid for unloaded condition. Is this acceptable?

Comment: It won't be that precise but it'll be in the right ballpark, and somewhere below 10% PWM it'll probably stop altogether. A calibration table (fill it by experiment) will get you close but speed will also depend on the load on the motor. For exact RPM, use positional feedback and a speed control loop.

Comment: see my answer here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/473410/how-to-calculate-speed-of-dc-motor/642994#642994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you can calculate the RPM as a proportion using the duty cycle.

A 100% duty cycle (analogWrite(motorpin, 255);) should give you the full speed of 16 RPM.  A duty cycle of 50% (analogWrite(motorpin, 127);) should give you 8 RPM.

Practically, you will find that the rotation speed won't be exactly 16 RPM on the full 12V.  The proportional rotation speed won't be exact, either.

Additionally, any load on the motor will change the rotation speed.

You can estimate an expected motor speed for a given PWM duty cycle, but it will only be (somewhat) valid when there's no load on the the motor.  Any load at all will slow it down.

If the rotation speed matters you will have to measure it.  There are various ways to do so.  The simplest is to measure the time for one pulse per rotation.